# Почему Internet Explorer выводит название сайта, а FireFox нет?

Tags: xsl

Почему InternetExplorer (версия 8.0.7601.17514) выводит название сайта, а FireFox (версия 95.0.2) нет?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="body">
        <h1>
            <xsl:value-of select="//runningHead/siteName" />
        </h1>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

site.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="SiteParts/Appearance/xslStyle.xsl" ?>
<body>
    <runningHead>
        <logotype>
            <img>SiteParts\Appearance\logotype.PNG</img>
            <alt>Логотип</alt>
        </logotype>
        <siteName>Название сайта</siteName>
    </runningHead>
</body>
```

Я в InternetExplorer открываю файл site.xml и появляется надпись крупным жирным шрифтом: "Название сайта", а в FireFox такой надписи нет.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Где выводит? Как вы это открываете?